# How to Get post created date and also post user

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am trying to get the post created date in this format `Jun 20, 2020` when i do this `{{ post.created_at }}` it shows like this `Fri Jul 03 2020 23:43:41 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)` i want to change it to show `Jun 20, 2020`.

And also i have a posts table in my database and i have `user_id` column which contains the id of the user that make the post, how can i get the username, i tried doing this `{{ post.users.username }}` and it shows undefined

Model

```
'use strict'

const Model = use('Model')
const moment = require('moment');
const date = new Date();

class Post extends Model {

static formatDates (field, value) {
        if (field === 'created_at') {
          return value.format('MMM D, YYYY')
        }
        return super.formatDates(field, value)
      }
}
```

My View

```
<h1>{{ post.created_at }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to format your date.

Make changes in your code accordingly.

```
const moment = require('moment');
const date = new Date();

console.log(moment(date).format("MMM D, YYYY")
```

As I can see in documentation you have to format your date inside your model

Example

```
class User extends Model {
  static formatDates (field, value) {
    if (field === 'created_at') {
      return value.format('MMM D, YYYY')
    }
    return super.formatDates(field, value)
  }
}


  static castDates(field, value) {
    if (field === 'created_at') {
      return value.format('MMM D, YYYY')
    }
  }
```

I think castDate should work.

Adonis uses `moment` internally

Comment: how do i display it on my adonis view?

Comment: can you post your snippet ?

Comment: here it is ```<h1>[{{ post.created_at }}]</h1>``` i want it to show like ```Jul, 06,2020```

Comment: Updated my answer. Check now

Comment: It is till showing like this ```Sun Jul 05 2020 16:00:38 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)``` instead of ```Jul, 06 2020``` i have updated my question to show my model.. Also i am using AdonisJs V4.1

Comment: Check now as I understand adonis from documentation. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the format without using any package in that way.

```js
var date = new Date('Fri Jul 03 2020 23:43:41 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)').toDateString();
console.log([date.slice(4, 7), ',', date.slice(7)].join(''))
```